# consuming java based web service in vc++

Tags: java, web-services, visual-c++

i am developing a small application which consumes java based web service `(this service has dependency on one windows service, it should be running while making XML request)` from my vc++ WIN32 application. in this application i am facing strange problem. let me tell u how i am calling web methods.

i created a function which sends XML request(XML text) to a particular URL and receives response XML and parse that. i don't want to use proxy class (cannot use .net framework in my app, this is the condition). So when i sent XML request it returned me `Method 'msgs:CheckService' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized`. whereas same XML request works fine on SOAPUI application (i mean i am getting the expected response). My service URL is `http:\\localhost:1234`, I am using same URL in SOAPUI URL field.

One more thing when i tested my VC++ function with .Net based demo web-service it worked as expected but when i change URL and XML text to java web service it doesn't.

**EDITED**

I am not able to generate wsdl (appending `?wsdl` in URL) from above URL, which seems to me very strange...

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

thanks SO members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear what works for you and what does not. I think you are saying:

```
SOAPUI App ----XML Payload ----> Web Service
```

works, while

```
Your App ----  Exact same XML Payload --->  Web Sevice
```

In which case I'm afraid we're in a bit of a "Bugs Bunny" situation: "Something scwewy is going on here." Fundamentally the Web Service should be responding identically to the same input.

My suspicion would be that you actually are not quite sending the same data, you think you are but there's some subtle encoding or transforming thing going on. So I would first get some kind of network monitoring tool to look at exactly what is going over the wire. My bet is that you'll see something different in the two cases.

Comment: you got my problem, i guess u want to say i am not sending same XML in my app. let me tell you one thing i am sending XML copied from VS QuickWatch window. So i think there should be no error. As i told in my post that I am able to run same code with .Net based web-service (only i am changing URL and XML text). May be this service URL could be culprit as .Net based web-service url ends with .asmx and other java web-service with some `localhost:8080/services/` like that. but SOAPUI is able to invoke service but my app doesn't... thnks for reply

Comment: I don't understand how you can have a different URL for the same web service apsx or not. If you are changing URL then it's not really the same service. You need to see what's going over the wire, there are plenty of tools for doing this - I have some in my Java environment, surely you have some in yours.

Comment: i was just giving you example.